# How to extract the columns using the set collection in java?

Tags: java

Just started learning java

I have the following dataset

```
Date first seen          Duration Proto      Source IP Addr:Port     Destination IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows
2013-03-03 23:54:46.574     8.000 UDP      108.169.77.76:12345 ->    108.169.0.112:53           5      325     1
2013-03-03 23:59:51.984     0.000 UDP     100.253.69.196:62458 ->  100.256.234.129:1947         1       68     1
2013-03-03 23:59:52.048     0.000 UDP      108.450.45.35:123124 ->    108.123.0.987:9101        2     1686     1
```

I would like to write a program in Java to obtain only a column of Source IP address and a column of destination IP address ? Can someone show me an example code of how this can be done ?

Comment: Do you have a code? thoughts?

Comment: Where is this dataset located? A text file?

Comment: Split each line on whitespace, take the 5th and the 7th element.

Comment: how did u get this dataset?

Comment: this comes from a text file. I edited the IP address

Comment: I am a beginner in Java, I dont know how to write a code that would allow me to take out the columns.

Comment: I would love to see some exmaple code to at least grasp an idea of how to proceed

Answer (score 3):

It would be much simpler to split the input line using one or more spaces as a separator

```
String line =
    "2013-03-03 23:54:46.574     8.000 UDP      108.169.77.76:12345 ->    108.169.0.112:53           5      325     1";

String[] split = line.split(" +");
System.out.println(split[4]);
System.out.println(split[6]);
```

This outputs:

```
108.169.77.76:12345
108.169.0.112:53
```

Now reusing `split` method we could separate IP address from the port:

```
String[] split = line.split(" +");
System.out.println(split[4].split(":")[0]);
System.out.println(split[6].split(":")[0]);
```

This outputs the IP addresses without ports:

```
108.169.77.76
108.169.0.112
```

Please, beware, that this solution is missing checks, that would prevent your from getting  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception in case, your data looks not as you expected. You have always to verity the count of elements in an array before using `[..]` operator.

**Update:** IPv6 Adresses

If IPv6 addresses are possible you can use:

```
String[] split = line.split(" +");
System.out.println(getIP(split[4]));
System.out.println(getIP(split[6]));
```

with

```
private static String getIP(String ipWithPort) {
    int index = ipWithPort.lastIndexOf(":");
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format: " + ipWithPort);
    }
    return ipWithPort.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have encountered a problem: A few of the IP address appear in the form:  2001:63..b1:fe9d.88, where there are multiple ":" in the address, how should I split the IP address above by just truncating the part after the last semicolon ?

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @BorisBrodski answer:

A text file should be split in rows. In Java, you can do this with a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```
try {
    File file = new File("/where/my/file/is.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // ... do something with `line`
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // ... handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ... handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you read a text file with your input data line by line. Then you can use this snippet to parse each line and obtain source and destination IP addresses:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static final String REGEX_IP = "(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}";
    private static final Pattern LINE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "(" + REGEX_IP + "):[0-9]+\\s+->\\s+(" + REGEX_IP + "):[0-9]+");

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String line =
            "2013-03-03 23:54:46.574     8.000 UDP      108.169.77.76:12345 ->    108.169.0.112:53           5      325     1";

        Matcher matcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Source IP: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("Destination IP: " + matcher.group(2));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }
    }
}
```

Regex matcher parses the line (`find()` method) and, if match was found, provides both IP addresses within the matching groups `(...)`:

- `matcher.group(1)` - source IP
- `matcher.group(2)` - destination IP